# How to drop request in tornado?

Tags: python, tornado

In order to test my client, I want to make some of the HTTP request sent by my client doesn't get any response.

For example, I want every request should have cookie `topsession`, if not, no response.

```
class EchoHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if not self.get_cookie("topsession"):
            ###TODO
        else:
            self.write("0")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decorate your method with `asynchronous` and never call `finish`:

```
class EchoHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        if not self.get_cookie("topsession"):
            pass
        else:
            self.finish("0")
```

As the [docs for asynchronous say](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.asynchronous):

> If this decorator is given, the response is not finished when the method returns. It is up to the request handler to call self.finish() to finish the HTTP request.

So, if you simply return without calling `finish`, the client waits forever (or until its client-side socket timeout) for a response without receiving one. If you do this, however, you must call `finish` in the other branch of the if statement.

On the other hand if by "no response" you mean an error, you could do instead:

```
class EchoHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if not self.get_cookie("topsession"):
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(401)  # Unauthorized.
        else:
            self.write("0")
```

Answer (score 1):

The request's underlying connection can be closed explicitly

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.gen import coroutine

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @coroutine
    def get(self):
        self.request.connection.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

And the test with curl:

```
curl http://localhost:8888/ -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8888 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8888
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

The above code closes connection with `FIN`-flow and leaves the response empty. If you require to drop connection with reset - `RST` you can force it. Just set `SO_LINGER` for the connection's socket. You may consider the api as public since there is no `_`, but...  it's kind a internal stuff (implementation dependent) of Tornado.

```
import socket
import struct
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.gen import coroutine

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @coroutine
    def get(self):
        s = self.request.connection.stream.socket
        l_onoff = 1
        l_linger = 0
        s.setsockopt(
            socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_LINGER,
            struct.pack('ii', l_onoff, l_linger)
        )
        self.request.connection.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```